# QDBusInterface Upower Properties in Python are None

Tags: python, c++, qt, properties

I am trying to convert some c++/qt code to Python/qt.

Using QDBusInterface in c++:

```
auto qi = make_unique<QDBusInterface>("org.freedesktop.UPower", /org/freedesktop/UPower, "org.freedesktop.UPower", QDBusConnection::systemBus());
```

at this point I can already read values from it's properties:

```
   auto prop = qi.property("OnBattery");
```

Unfortunately it does not work that way while doing the same in Python:

```
qi = QDBusInterface(serviceObject, path, interface, QDBusConnection.systemBus())
```

qi.isValid() returns True but reading property:

```
onBattery = qi.property("OnBattery")
```

returns None.

Also calling methods like EnumerateDevices works on both C++ and Python

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is lack of good examples:

```
from PyQt5.QtDBus import QDBusConnection, QDBusInterface, QDBusMessage

# DBus connection and Interface.
dbus_service = 'org.freedesktop.UPower'
dbus_path = '/org/freedesktop/UPower'
interface = QDBusInterface(dbus_service, dbus_path, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties', QDBusConnection.systemBus())

# Get all properties.
msg = interface.call('GetAll', 'org.freedesktop.UPower')
print(msg.arguments())
for k, v in msg.arguments()[0].items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))

# Get just the requested property.
msg = interface.call('Get', 'org.freedesktop.UPower', 'OnBattery')
print(msg.arguments()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found indirect solution on my own.

It was resigning from using `QDBusInterface` and switching to Python's `dbus` which API can be used like in this [link](https://github.com/wogscpar/upower-python)